# Convert File to .txt with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert a file with no extension to a .txt extension with powershell so it can be picked up by some of our automated processes. I am not having any luck with basic powershell outputs

Comment: Please explain why you need to convert the file. Is there more to it than simply adding the .txt extension? What have you tried yourself an why did that fail?

Comment: Hi Badger, welcome to SO! SO is not a code writing site and this type of question isn't applicable here. Try posting this on a different site or edit your question to make it more suitable for this site! See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: However, I can give you a suggestion. Try using `get-content` on your file and storing it into a variable then using `$var > newfile.txt`

Comment: do you only want to change the filename oder does the content within the file also needs to be converted? (Try Move-Item to rename or Copy-Item to dublicate the file and give it a new name)

Comment: I am trying to keep the filename the same but convert it to a .txt. I'm not sure if just doing a name change in powershell would work or if i need to do a conversion of filetype

Comment: Maybe you should attempt it and see what would work. What have you tried?

Comment: Convert not a matter of changing the extension. Covert means changing the object. Especially if the file is not really a text file. Others have given you options to try. Try them. Extension change is a rename, not a convert. Use the Rename-Item cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

if contents id readable in .txt format try rename it, and add extension to originalfile name value.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment. This is really 'intro to Powershell stuff', and you could have just as easily done this with cmd.exe ren as well.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\temp' -Filter '*NoEx*'

# Results
<#
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        20-May-20     11:40             94 FileWithNoExtension   
#>

Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\FileWithNoExtension'

#Results
<#
a=abcdef123
b=ngh567
c=defh123
case
Case
#>

Rename-Item -Path 'D:\Temp\FileWithNoExtension' -NewName 'D:\Temp\FileWithNoExtension.txt' -WhatIf

# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\FileWithNoExtension Destination: D:\Temp\FileWithNoExtension.txt ".
#>

Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\temp' -Filter '*NoEx*'
# Results
<#
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        20-May-20     11:40             94 FileWithNoExtension  
#>
Rename-Item -Path 'D:\Temp\FileWithNoExtension' -NewName 'D:\Temp\FileWithNoExtension.txt'
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\temp' -Filter '*NoEx*'
# Results
<#
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        20-May-20     11:40             94 FileWithNoExtension.txt
#>
```